# Rails REST API for mobile apps. Sessions

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, session, ios4

I am creating a mobile app that has users and talks to a custom Rails REST API for the backend.  Should I create a session when logging in? Or should I just send the username and password with each request? If sessions is the way to go, how is that normally implemented?

Comment: http://matteomelani.wordpress.com/2011/10/17/authentication-for-mobile-devices/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

simply generate tokens, and use them to identify users