# Problems allowing user sign in with rest api

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, rest

I have been creating an app that allows users to sign in and out of their accounts. My problem is that I am trying to use a rest api to make it work with an iphone app. In the app, users would be able to sign in and out of their accounts. To do this on the web app, I do as listed bellow. Instead of using cookies, I have read that the better way to do for the iphone app would be through a token according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10669901/rails-rest-api-for-mobile-apps-sessions). Would I simple send the remember_token back when a user is created or signs in through a json or is there more to it than that. If sending the token is the correct way, would I have to include it every time I send a post from the app when a user is signed in and how would I do this?

To sign in:

```
def sign_in(user)
  remember_token = User.new_remember_token
  cookies.permanent[:remember_token] = remember_token
  user.update_attribute(:remember_token, User.hash(remember_token))
  self.current_user = user
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're correct about sending back the token. But you need to set that on the http headers for the iPhone app. Then in your app when you authenticate or look up the user you would use that token. You can access the token in rails using request.headers["Whateved-You-Call-Token"].

Comment: One question, I have set the header on the rails side and retrieved it on the ios side. I was still wordering if I have to do this `if (yourConfig.csrfToken && ![request.httpMethod isEqualToString:@"GET"])
  [request setValue:yourConfig.csrfToken forHTTPHeaderField:@"X-CSRF-Token"];` for every request I make, or if there is a way to make this execute every time I send the request

Comment: In the app I work on we use AFNetworking and subclass the HttpClient and set the headers on the object. Then each subsequent request has the header.

Comment: On the rails side, to find the user, I would do something like this - `@key = request.headers['X-TOKEN']
@user = User.find_by_remember_token(@key)`